# Is there a "normal" EqualQ function in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

On the documentation page for `Equal` we read that

> Approximate numbers with machine
>   precision or higher are considered
>   equal if they differ in at most their
>   last seven binary digits (roughly
>   their last two decimal digits).

Here are examples (32 bit system; for 64 bit system add some more zeros in the middle):

```
In[1]:= 1.0000000000000021 == 1.0000000000000022
1.0000000000000021 === 1.0000000000000022

Out[1]= True

Out[2]= True
```

I'm wondering is there a "normal" analog of the `Equal` function in *Mathematica* that does not drop last 7 binary digits?

Comment: Would `SameQ` be ok? Maybe after truncating to the number of digits that you want to keep.

Comment: @Simon Try `1.00000000000000000022 === 1.00000000000000000021`. You will see that it is not OK. :(

Comment: A guess...perhaps Mathematica doesn't consider last digit to be a significant digit at default precision. You could use backtick notation to indicate that precision is high enough to make all digits significant -- 1.00000000000000000022`100===1.00000000000000000021`100

Comment: @Alexey - that's why I said you'd have to truncate to the number of digits that you want to compare.

Comment: `SameQ` help says it ignores the last binary digit for `Real` objects

Comment: @Alexey btw, hardware floating point can give non-deterministic results, perhaps that's the reason `===` drops digit -- http://thenumericalalgorithmsgroup.blogspot.com/2011/02/wandering-precision.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In[12]:= MyEqual[x_, y_] := Order[x, y] == 0

In[13]:= MyEqual[1.0000000000000021, 1.0000000000000022]

Out[13]= False

In[14]:= MyEqual[1.0000000000000021, 1.0000000000000021]

Out[14]= True
```

This tests if two object are identical, since 1.0000000000000021 and 1.000000000000002100 differs in precision they won't be considered as identical.

Comment: Precision in Mathematica is separate from digits shown. E.g., 1.01`16 and 1.01000`16 have the same precision.

Comment: @Timo: Precision[1.0000000000000021] is MachinePrecision (1.0000000000000021\`) but Precision[1.000000000000002100] is 18 (1.000000000000002100\`18). The representation does affect the internal representation. Try FullForm[] them.

Comment: @Kenny: And yet both 1.1 and 1.10000 are MachinePrecision ;-). My interpretation of the OP is that he wants to compare numerical values, not just what the numbers look like (SameQ@@ToString/@{#1,#2}& would suffice for that, or indeed your Order[]).

Comment: @Timo: That's because 1.1 and 1.100000 have less than ~16 digits which can be represented by MachinePrecision (IEEE double).

Comment: `Order` -- good idea! A nice simple, built-in function.  Granted, it does not ignore trailing zeroes but, in general, comparing close numbers with different precisions is a tricky business.  It frequently requires detailed numerical analysis, informed by the specific application.  If you want that level of control, then a `RealDigits` solution like @Timo's will likely be required.  But I like the simplicity of `Order`, letting Mathematica's ordering policy handle the gnarly cases.  +1

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to recent [post](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/3bab2bc9f74ba809) on the official newsgroup by Oleksandr Rasputinov, now I have learned two undocumented functions which control the tolerance of `Equal` and `SameQ`: `$EqualTolerance` and `$SameQTolerance`. In *Mathematica* version 5 and earlier these functions live in the `` Experimental` `` context and are well documented: [$EqualTolerance](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/AdditionalFunctions/ExperimentalContext/NumericalComputation/$EqualTolerance.html),  [$SameQTolerance](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/AdditionalFunctions/ExperimentalContext/NumericalComputation/$SameQTolerance.html). Starting from version 6, they are [moved to the `` Internal` `` context](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/1df08919cdc2790a/31258bb2cbe14156) and become undocumented but still work and even have built-in diagnostic messages which appear when one try to assign them illegal values:

```
In[1]:= Internal`$SameQTolerance = a

During evaluation of In[2]:= Internal`$SameQTolerance::tolset: 
Cannot set Internal`$SameQTolerance to a; value must be a real 
number or +/- Infinity.

Out[1]= a
```

Citing Oleksandr Rasputinov:

> Internal`$EqualTolerance ... takes a
>   machine real value indicating the
>   number of decimal digits' tolerance
>   that should be applied, i.e.
>   Log[2]/Log[10] times the number of
>   least   significant bits one wishes to
>   ignore.

In this way, setting `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` to zero will force `Equal` to consider numbers equal only when they are identical in all binary digits (not considering out-of-`Precision` digits):

```
In[2]:= Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, 
           1.0000000000000021 == 1.0000000000000022]
Out[2]= False

In[5]:= Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, 
           1.00000000000000002 == 1.000000000000000029]
        Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, 
           1.000000000000000020 == 1.000000000000000029]
Out[5]= True
Out[6]= False
```

Note the following case:

```
In[3]:= Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, 
           1.0000000000000020 == 1.0000000000000021]
        RealDigits[1.0000000000000020, 2] === RealDigits[1.0000000000000021, 2]
Out[3]= True
Out[4]= True
```

In this case both numbers have `MachinePrecision` which effectively is

```
In[5]:= $MachinePrecision
Out[5]= 15.9546
```

(`53*Log[10, 2]`). With such precision these numbers are identical in all binary digits:

```
In[6]:= RealDigits[1.0000000000000020` $MachinePrecision, 2] === 
                   RealDigits[1.0000000000000021` $MachinePrecision, 2]
Out[6]= True
```

Increasing precision to 16 makes them different arbitrary-precision numbers:

```
In[7]:= RealDigits[1.0000000000000020`16, 2] === 
              RealDigits[1.0000000000000021`16, 2]
Out[7]= False

In[8]:= Row@First@RealDigits[1.0000000000000020`16,2]
         Row@First@RealDigits[1.0000000000000021`16,2]
Out[9]= 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010010
Out[10]= 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010011
```

But unfortunately `Equal` still fails to distinguish them:

```
In[11]:= Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, 
 {1.00000000000000002`16 == 1.000000000000000021`16, 
  1.00000000000000002`17 == 1.000000000000000021`17, 
  1.00000000000000002`18 == 1.000000000000000021`18}]
Out[11]= {True, True, False}
```

There is an infinite number of such cases:

```
In[12]:= Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, 
  Cases[Table[a = SetPrecision[1., n]; 
    b = a + 10^-n; {n, a == b, RealDigits[a, 2] === RealDigits[b, 2], 
     Order[a, b] == 0}, {n, 15, 300}], {_, True, False, _}]] // Length

Out[12]= 192
```

Interestingly, sometimes `RealDigits` returns identical digits while `Order` shows that internal representations of expressions are not identical:

```
In[13]:= Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, 
  Cases[Table[a = SetPrecision[1., n]; 
    b = a + 10^-n; {n, a == b, RealDigits[a, 2] === RealDigits[b, 2], 
     Order[a, b] == 0}, {n, 15, 300}], {_, _, True, False}]] // Length

Out[13]= 64
```

But it seems that opposite situation newer happens:

```
In[14]:= 
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, 
  Cases[Table[a = SetPrecision[1., n]; 
    b = a + 10^-n; {n, a == b, RealDigits[a, 2] === RealDigits[b, 2], 
     Order[a, b] == 0}, {n, 15, 3000}], {_, _, False, True}]] // Length

Out[14]= 0
```

Comment: Thank you for finding and posting this. +1  (Why did this not have any votes?)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Added further observations. It seems that ``Internal`$EqualTolerance`` is not so reliable as one may expect...

Comment: Strongly relevant MathGroups post by Itai Seggev (Wolfram Research): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/5zszL5urhYA/KK5BdTIC1yYJ

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
realEqual[a_, b_] := SameQ @@ RealDigits[{a, b}, 2, Automatic]
```

The choice of base 2 is crucial to ensure that you are comparing the internal representations.

```
In[54]:= realEqual[1.0000000000000021, 1.0000000000000021]
Out[54]= True

In[55]:= realEqual[1.0000000000000021, 1.0000000000000022]
Out[55]= False

In[56]:= realEqual[
           1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022
         , 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023
         ]
Out[56]= False
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of an already defined operator. But you may define for example:

```
longEqual[x_, y_] := Block[{$MaxPrecision = 20, $MinPrecision = 20},
                            Equal[x - y, 0.]]
```

Such as:

```
longEqual[1.00000000000000223, 1.00000000000000223]
True
longEqual[1.00000000000000223, 1.00000000000000222]
False
```

**Edit**

If you want to generalize for an arbitrary number of digits, you can do for example:

```
longEqual[x_, y_] :=
 Block[{
   $MaxPrecision =  Max @@ StringLength /@ ToString /@ {x, y},
   $MinPrecision =  Max @@ StringLength /@ ToString /@ {x, y}},
   Equal[x - y, 0.]]
```

So that your counterexample in your comment also works.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you. But adding more zeros always breaks this approach: `longEqual[1.\
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
0000000000000000000000000023, \
1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000022]`

Comment: It works better but fails when at least one of the numbers ends with `NumberMark`: longEqual[1.0000000000000223`, 1.0000000000000222]

Comment: @Alexey If you want to preserve precision you should use 1.``55 and not 1.`` alone

Answer (score 5):

I propose a strategy that uses `RealDigits` to compare the actual digits of the numbers. The only tricky bit is stripping out trailing zeroes.

```
trunc = {Drop[First@#, Plus @@ First /@ {-Dimensions@First@#, 
         Last@Position[First@#, n_?(# != 0 &)]}], Last@#} &@ RealDigits@# &;
exactEqual = SameQ @@ trunc /@ {#1, #2} &;

In[1]  := exactEqual[1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111,
                     1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111000]
Out[1] := True
In[2]  := exactEqual[1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111,
                     1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000112000]
Out[2] := False
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you really have to specify what you want... there's no way to compare approximate real numbers that will satisfy everyone in every situation.

Anyway, here's a couple more options:

```
In[1]:= realEqual[lhs_,rhs_,tol_:$MachineEpsilon] := 0==Chop[lhs-rhs,tol]

In[2]:= Equal[1.0000000000000021,1.0000000000000021]
        realEqual[1.0000000000000021,1.0000000000000021]
Out[2]= True
Out[3]= True

In[4]:= Equal[1.0000000000000022,1.0000000000000021]
        realEqual[1.0000000000000022,1.0000000000000021]
Out[4]= True
Out[5]= False
```

As the precision of both numbers gets higher, then they can always be distinguished if you set `tol` high enough.

Note that the subtraction is done at the precision of the lowest of the two numbers. You could make it happen at the precision of the higher number (which seems a bit pointless) by doing something like

```
maxEqual[lhs_, rhs_] := With[{prec = Max[Precision /@ {lhs, rhs}]}, 
  0 === Chop[SetPrecision[lhs, prec] - SetPrecision[rhs, prec], 10^-prec]]
```

maybe using the minimum precision makes more sense

```
minEqual[lhs_, rhs_] := With[{prec = Min[Precision /@ {lhs, rhs}]}, 
  0 === Chop[SetPrecision[lhs, prec] - SetPrecision[rhs, prec], 10^-prec]]
```

Answer (score 2):

One other way to define such function is by using SetPrecision:

```
MyEqual[a_, b_] := SetPrecision[a, Precision[a] + 3] == SetPrecision[b, Precision[b] + 3]
```

This seems to work in the all cases but I'm still wondering is there a built-in function. It is ugly to use high-level functions for such a primitive task...

Comment: It only works if Precision is the same as the length of your number, which very often is not the case. MyEqual[1.111`3, 1.11100001`3] -> True.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov: Instead of setting precision, I like to set a tolerable percentage of deviation from the TRUE value. For example, let us suppose that I have a true value for `xT=245` and a false value `xF=250`, but I want to set `xT=xF` because the percentage deviation from the True value is only 2% and I want to tolerate this deviation and accept the equality like in significance test. I have a very large number of equations to tolerate but I do not know how to set this tolerance level for my system of equations. Can you help me to solve this problem? thanks.

Comment: @TugrulTemel I suggest you to create a specific question on the [dedicated site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), with detailed description and examples of what you wish to achieve.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: Yes, I will do that right now. thanks for your prompt reply. Regards, Tugrul