# Difference between == and === in Mathematica

Tags: comparison, wolfram-mathematica, equals-operator

I was under the impression that `=` is an assignment, `==` is a numeric comparison, and `===` is a symbolic comparison (as well as in some other languages `==` being `equal to` and `===` being `identical to`. However, looking at the following it would appear that this is not necessarily the case...

```
In: x == x
Out: True

In: x === x
Out: True

In: 5 == 5
Out: True

In: 5 === 5
Out: True

In: x = 5
Out: 5

In: 5 == x
Out: True

In: 5 === x
Out: True

In: 5 5 == 5x
Out: True

In: 5 5 === 5x
Out: True

In: x == y
Out: x == y

In: x === y
Out: False

In: y = x
Out: 5

In: x == y
Out: True

In: x === y
Out: True
```

So what exactly is the difference between == and === in Mathematica? I have been looking at the documentation but I still don't quite understand it.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983885/is-there-a-normal-equalq-function-in-mathematica/6626748#6626748) answer for additional information on numerical behavior of `Equal` and `SameQ`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One important difference is that `===` always returns `True` or `False`.  `==` can return unevaluated (which is why it's useful for representing equations.)

```
In[7]:= y == x^2 + 1

Out[7]= y == 1 + x^2

In[8]:= y === x^2 + 1

Out[8]= False
```

There are some interesting cases where `==` returns unevaluated that are worth being aware of while programming.  For example:

```
In[10]:= {} == 1

Out[10]= {} == 1
```

which can affect things like `If[foo=={}, <true>, <false>]`.

Answer (score 14):

`==` and `===` are very similar in the sense that it returns `True` if the lhs and rhs are equal. One example where they differ is when you compare numbers in different representation formats.

```
In: 5.==5
Out: True

In: 5.===5
Out: False
```

Although they are the same numerically, (which is why `==` returns `True`), they aren't exactly identical.

FYI, they are different functions internally. `==` is `Equal`, whereas `===` is `SameQ`.

Answer (score 14):

`Equal` refers to semantic equality whereas `SameQ` is syntactic equality. For instance, `Sin[x]^2+Cos[x]^2` and `1` are the same number, so they are equal semantically. Since this can not be determined without more transformations, `Equal` returns unevaluated. However, actual expressions are different, so `SameQ` gives `False`.

```
Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1
Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 === 1
Simplify[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1]
```

Note that there's special handling of `Real` numbers, `SameQ[a,b]` can return `True` if `a` and `b` differ in the last binary digit. To do more restrictive identity testing, use  `Order[a,b]==0`

```
a = 1. + 2^-52;
b = 1.;
a === b
Order[a, b]==0
```

`SameQ` can return `True` for expressions that are syntactically different because expression heads may sort arguments automatically. You can prevent automatic sorting by using holding attributes. For instance

```
c + d === d + c
SetAttributes[SameQ, HoldAll]
c + d === d + c
```

Comment: Could you please include an example of **SameQ[a,b] can return True if a and b differ in the last binary digit.**? Thanks!

Comment: Added example, using the fact that mantissa of double has 53 digits

Answer (score 7):

> lhs===rhs yields True if the
>   expression lhs is identical to rhs,
>   and yields False otherwise.

and

> lhs==rhs returns True if lhs and rhs
>   are identical.

Reference from [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SameQ.html) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Equal.html).

Answer (score 2):

I direct you to [section 2.5: Equality checks](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node24.html)  of an excellent book by Leonid Shifrin.