# Mathematica: conditional "compilation"

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, conditional-compilation

I'm trying to make a conditinal expression which would initialize some functions, variables etc.. Something which would look like this in C:

```
#if option==1
  int foo(int x){/*some code here*/}
  int q=10;
#else
  char foo(int x){/*some other code*/}
  double q=3.141592;
#endif
use_q(q);
f(some_var);
```

In Mathematica I've tried using If, like this:

```
If[option==1,
foo[x_]=some_expression1;
q=10;
,
foo[x_]=some_expression2;
q=3.141592;
]
use_q[q];
f[some_var];
```

But the result is that functions' arguments are colored red, and nothing gets initialized or computed inside If.
So, how should I do instead to get conditional "compilation"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several things:

1. Do *not* use blanks (underscores) in variable names - in Mathematica these are reserved symbols, representing patterns.
2. In case you condition does not evaluate to `True` or `False`, `If` does not evaluate either.

Thus:

```
In[12]:= If[option==1,Print["1"],Print["Not 1"]]
Out[12]= If[option==1,Print[1],Print[Not 1]]
```

thus your result. Red colred arguments are not the issue in this particular case. You should either use `===` in place of `==`,  or `TrueQ[option==1]`, to get what you want. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286736/difference-between-and-in-mathematica), for more information.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that underscores won't work. But your second point made me understand what I was doing wrong: I was doing comparison of option with undefined variable, thinking that it'd work as a symbol, but if the symbols are different, mathematica can't say if they're equal, so this is my mistake.

Comment: Just following up with the underscores. As of at least version 11, you can use the `\[LetterSpace]` character in place of underscores much concern. These look like thinner underscores, and may also be typed with the keystrokes `Esc` `l` `s` `Esc` or `Esc` `_` `Esc`

Comment: @TaylorScott That's interesting to know, but I personally prefer ASCII characters in code.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like something that would be better done as a function with an option, for example

```
Options[myfunction,{Compiled->False}]

myfunction[x_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
   With[{comp= TrueQ[OptionValue[Compiled]]},
    If[comp, compiledFunction[x], notcompiledFunction[x] ]]
```

(The local constant `comp` within the `With` statement is not strictly necessary for this example but would be useful if your code is at all complex and you use this conditional more than once.)

I do not recommend defining different cases of a function inside an `If[]` statement. You would be better off using the built-in pattern-matching abilities in Mathematica. (See documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Patterns.html) and especially [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html).)

Some useful documentation on options within functions can be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionsPattern.html), [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingOptions.html).