# Is Put - Get cycle in Mathematica always deterministic?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In *Mathematica* as in other systems of computer math the numbers are internally stored in binary form. However when exporting them with such functions as `Put` and `PutAppend` they are converted into approximate decimals. When you import them back with such functions as `Get` they are restored from this approximate decimal representation to binary form.

The question is whether the recovered number is always identical to the original binary number and, if not always, in which cases it is not and how large can be the difference? I am particularly interested in the `Put` - `Get` cycle (on the same computer system).

The following two simple experiments show that probably the `Put` - `Get` cycle in *Mathematica* always restores original numbers exactly even for arbitrary precision numbers:

```
In[1]:= list=RandomReal[{-10^6,10^6},10000];
Put[list,"test.txt"];
list2=Get["test.txt"];
Order[list,list2]===0
Order[Total@Abs[list-list2],0.]===0

Out[4]= True
Out[5]= True


In[6]:= list=SetPrecision[RandomReal[{-10^6,10^6},10000],50];
Put[list,"test.txt"];
list2=Get["test.txt"];
Order[list,list2]===0
Total@Abs[list-list2]//InputForm

Out[9]= True
Out[10]//InputForm=
0``39.999515496936205
```

But maybe I am missing something?

---

### UPDATE

With more correct test code I have found that in reality these tests show only that restored numbers have identical binary `RealDigits` but their `Precision`s may differ even in `Equal` sense. Here are more correct tests:

```
test := (Put[list, "test.txt"];
  list2 = Get["test.txt"];
  {Order[list, list2] === 0,
   Order[Total@Abs[list - list2], 0.] === 0,
   Total[Order @@@ RealDigits[Transpose[{list, list2}], 2]],
   Total[Order @@@ Map[Precision, Transpose[{list, list2}], {-1}]],
   Total[1 - Boole[Equal @@@ Map[Precision, Transpose[{list, list2}], {-1}]]]})

In[8]:= list=RandomReal[NormalDistribution[],10000]^1001;
test
Out[9]= {False,True,0,1,3}
In[6]:= list=RandomReal[NormalDistribution[],10000,WorkingPrecision->50]^1001;
test
Out[7]= {False,False,0,-2174,1}
```

Comment: Disadvantage of using `RandomReal[{-10^6,10^6},10000]` is that the probability of generating numbers in the order of $MinMachineNumber is negligible. You're testing the big numbers only, not the small ones.

Comment: @Alexey I notice you are now using `NormalDistribution` to get more smaller numbers. However, the chance of getting those in the order of $MinMachineNumber is still negligible: `Probability[-\[Epsilon] <= x <= \[Epsilon], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]` ==>
`Piecewise[{{Erf[\[Epsilon]/Sqrt[2]], \[Epsilon] > 0}}, 0]`, which is 1.77535*10^-305 for epsilon = 1000 * $MinMachineNumber.

Comment: @Sjoerd You have not noticed that the random variable is raised to the power of 1001. Try `RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 100]^1001`. You will see many numbers even smaller than the `$MinMachineNumber` and bigger than the `$MaxMachineNumber`.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that one. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid I can't give a definitive answer. If you look into the text file you see it's stored as something like the InputForm of the values, including the precision indication for non-machine precision numbers.

Assuming that `Get` uses the same conversion routines as `ImportString` and `ExportString` your test can be sped up a tiny bit.

```
Monitor[
 Do[
  i = RandomReal[{$MinMachineNumber, 10 $MinMachineNumber}, 100000];
  If[i =!= 
    ToExpression[ImportString[ExportString[i, "Text"], "List"]], 
   Print[i]], {n, 100}
  ],
 n]
```

I have tested this for several hundreds of millions of numbers in various ranges between $MinMachineNumber and $MaxMachineNumber and I always get back the original numbers. It's no proof, of course, but it seems unlikely that you're going to see numbers for which this is not true if there are any (and in that case the difference would be so tiny as to be negligible).

Comment: You rely on `UnsameQ` in your code which "still considers `Real` numbers equal if they differ in their last binary digit." `Order` has no such disadvantage. See this thread for more information: "[Is there a “normal” `EqualQ` function in *Mathematica*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983885/is-there-a-normal-equalq-function-in-mathematica)".

Comment: And about `ExportString`: [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) shows that MathKernel creates a temporary file with output of `ExportString[i, "Text"]` in the user's temporary directory `%TEMP%`. So it seems that in this case there is no any benefit to use `ExportString` instead of `Put` since both of them work with file system.

Comment: @Alexey Good points. Now that I timed it, Put/Get seem to be twice as fast as the ImportString/ExportString. I assumed they would work in memory and thus be faster.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to know is that Put[] / Get[] doesn't keep packed arrays packed.  You should check out DumpSave[].  It's much faster as it's a binary format and keeps arrays packed.

Comment: I am aware of `DumpSave` but I am interested in exporting expressions in human-readable format. I am quite satisfied with the default ASCII-based representation created by `Put` and `PutAppend`. The only reason for concern is formulated in the question.